# Using new for an already valid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

If I've already used `new` to allocate memory to `int* p`, but then if I want use `new` again, will the previously allocated memory remain valid?

```
int *p;
p= new int[5]; //is this going to remain valid after the following statement?
p= new int[10];
```

If yes, then am I required to `delete[]` it? I tried doing that but the compiler says that the pointer is valid, so I can't delete it. Is there any other way to get rid of the previously allocated memory?

Comment: You will have to free previously allocated memory.

Comment: Its going to remain both valid *and* **leaked** forever in the ether.

Comment: `delete[] p` before `p=new[]` again. new operator will not free resources previously allocated, and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second use of `new[]` is, in itself, completely independent of the first. The second use of `new[]` does not in any way invalidate the first block of memory that you allocated.

When you allocate memory, you are asking the system to allocate memory, and tell you the address of the memory that it, the system, allocated. It is your responsibility to remember that address so that you can refer to it in the future. You need to be able to refer to the memory in order to access it and eventually deallocate it.

This is your code:

```
int *p;
p= new int[5];
p= new int[10];
```

The first assignment records the address of the first allocated block. The second assignment overwrites that value with the address of the second block.

So, the problem you have is that you no longer have a variable that contains the address of the first block of memory. Whilst that first block is still valid, you are unable to refer to it. In particular, since you can no longer refer to it, you cannot deallocate it and so it will be leaked.

If you wish to be able to deallocate both blocks of memory, then you have to be able to refer to both blocks. Which means that you must have two variables to hold the two distinct addresses.

```
int* p1 = new int[5]; 
int* p2 = new int[10];
```

Now you can refer to blocks blocks separately. When you are done, deallocate the memory:

```
delete[] p1;
delete[] p2;
```

On the other hand, if you want to delete the memory before allocating a new block, you can do that:

```
int* p = new int[5]; 
// use p
detete[] p;

int* p = new int[10];
// use p
delete[] p;
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to deallocate it if I had a separate pointer to which I can assign the previous block of memory, and then deallocate it using this separate pointer?

Comment: If both blocks of memory are in existence at the same time, you must have references to both blocks of memory. Which means to need two variables holding those references. How you achieve that is up to you. You cannot to it with a single int* as per the code in the question. How you achieve that is really up to you but you certainly need to have two pointer variables, one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

The prev remain somewhere on the heap. You can use valgrind to verify that. If you want to use the sane pointer again and again you might consider to create a function that delete the last allocation and allicate new space each time...

Comment: Other solution (if you want to keep all arrays till the end of your program) might be to maintain pointers array and to keep pointer to allocated place each time before you renew.. then when your progeam ends - run over this pointer array and delete all

Comment: Hard to see why valgrind is necessary to understand this @cmaster that seems a little over the top for a simple pointer leak

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, you are right, `valgrind` is not necessary in this case. It's not *necessary* in any case, you can always figure things out without it. But anyone starting to program in C/C++, having trouble figuring out pointers and memory allocations, should definitely hear about this awesome little tool.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what David Heffernan said, when you have this statement:

```
int *p;
p= new int[5];
```

don't think of `p` as being assigned to the memory that was allocated. The memory exists independently of `p`, but you're using `p` as a sort of post-it note to jot down where that memory is located. When you assign a new value to `p`, you're simply overwriting your note. You haven't done anything to the memory that was allocated-- you just don't know where it is anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory you previously allocated is not needed anymore, you have to use `delete []` to free the memory. Otherwise, the memory is still out there, but you have no way to access it any more, thus a **memory leak**.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `delete[] p;` in order to avoid memory leak.  The memory doesn't get released by itself.  What's the exact information the compiler is giving in terms of "can't delete it"?